# SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType returns true, though no account is configured

Tags: facebook, xcode7, ios9, slcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using the Social framework with XCode 7 beta / iOS 9 beta.  The Facebook app is installed on the (physical) device, but in settings, no account is configured.  According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SLComposeViewController/isAvailableForServiceType:):

> For the account to be available, the user must be logged into the
>   social service in the device settings.

Nonetheless, `SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook)` returns `true`.  Any idea why this should be?

As a side note:

```
let store = ACAccountStore()
let accountType = store.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook)
let accounts = store.accountsWithAccountType(accountType)
```

When not logged in, this returns `nil`; but when logged in, this returns an empty array type `[AnyObject]`.

Comment: Observing same behaviour on release version of iOS 9

Comment: I am seeing the same issue.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?